# Spring Cloud Function deployed on AWS Lambda fails with NullPointerException at FunctionalSpringApplication.java:102

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-function

I have a very simple Spring Cloud Functions with the AWS adapter to run it as an AWS Lambda. The source code is available on Github: https://github.com/codependent/spring-boot-authentication-function

```
@SpringBootApplication
class SpringBootAuthenticationFunctionApplication {

    @Bean
    fun kotlinSupplier(): (Credentials) -> AuthenticationResponse {

        return {
            if (it.user == "jose" && it.password == "MyPassword") {
                //HMAC
                val algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("secret")
                val token = JWT.create()
                        .withIssuer("MicronautAwsAuthenticationFunction")
                        .withSubject(it.user)
                        .sign(algorithm)
                AuthenticationResponse(token)
            } else {
                AuthenticationResponse()
            }
        }
    }

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<SpringBootAuthenticationFunctionApplication>(*args)
}
```

When I run this function on AWS Lambda it throws a NullPointerException. Any idea what's wrong?

```
{
  "errorMessage": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
  "errorType": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "org.springframework.cloud.function.context.FunctionalSpringApplication.postProcessApplicationContext(FunctionalSpringApplication.java:102)",
    "org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:372)",
    "org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)",
    "org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringFunctionInitializer.initialize(SpringFunctionInitializer.java:86)",
    "org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootStreamHandler.initialize(SpringBootStreamHandler.java:55)",
    "org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootStreamHandler.handleRequest(SpringBootStreamHandler.java:64)",
    "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)",
    "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)",
    "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)",
    "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)"
  ]
}
```

I have set `org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootStreamHandler` as the value of the handler class in the AWS Console.

**Full CloudWatch logs:**

```
16:12:39.252 [main] INFO org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringFunctionInitializer - Searching manifests: [jar:file:/var/runtime/lib/LambdaJavaRTEntry-1.0.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF, jar:file:/var/runtime/lib/aws-lambda-java-core-1.2.0.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF, file:/var/task/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF]
16:12:39.258 [main] INFO org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringFunctionInitializer - Searching manifest: jar:file:/var/runtime/lib/LambdaJavaRTEntry-1.0.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
16:12:39.259 [main] INFO org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringFunctionInitializer - Searching manifest: jar:file:/var/runtime/lib/aws-lambda-java-core-1.2.0.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
16:12:39.260 [main] INFO org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringFunctionInitializer - Searching manifest: file:/var/task/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
16:12:39.261 [main] INFO org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringFunctionInitializer - Searching manifests: []
16:12:39.261 [main] INFO org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringFunctionInitializer - Main class: null
START RequestId: 66460dc7-e90b-487c-a022-12c04ab72c7d Version: $LATEST
16:12:39.272 [main] INFO org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringFunctionInitializer - Initializing: null

. ____ _ __ _ _
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __ __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
\\/ ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| | ) ) ) )
' |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
=========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
:: Spring Boot ::

2019-03-21 16:12:45.617 ERROR 1 --- [ main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application run failed

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.FunctionalSpringApplication.postProcessApplicationContext(FunctionalSpringApplication.java:102) ~[task/:na]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:372) ~[task/:na]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) ~[task/:na]
at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringFunctionInitializer.initialize(SpringFunctionInitializer.java:86) [task/:na]
at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootStreamHandler.initialize(SpringBootStreamHandler.java:55) [task/:na]
at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootStreamHandler.handleRequest(SpringBootStreamHandler.java:64) [task/:na]
at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:888) [LambdaSandboxJava-1.0.jar:na]
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:293) [LambdaSandboxJava-1.0.jar:na]
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.<clinit>(AWSLambda.java:64) [LambdaSandboxJava-1.0.jar:na]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) [na:1.8.0_181]
at lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry.main(LambdaRTEntry.java:104) [LambdaJavaRTEntry-1.0.jar:na]
java.lang.NullPointerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.FunctionalSpringApplication.postProcessApplicationContext(FunctionalSpringApplication.java:102)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:372)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringFunctionInitializer.initialize(SpringFunctionInitializer.java:86)
at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootStreamHandler.initialize(SpringBootStreamHandler.java:55)
at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootStreamHandler.handleRequest(SpringBootStreamHandler.java:64)
```

Comment: Setting `MAIN_CLASS` to '<fully qualified main class name>' environment variable in AWS lambda worked for me.
Actual error is shown in logs if you upgrade Spring Cloud Function to version `2.1.0.RC1`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug, so please consider raising the issue [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/issues).